# Error handling, 500 internal server error

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is the response page that i get frmo my ajax request.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Do anyone have any idead why theres no error page? I do have the error controller and view to handle it, but it's no use, it don't work :/

Comment: There's no exception, this above is the only thing that shows when i request the page.

Comment: open your .htaccess file in your public folder and add `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development` on top, and see if it generated the exceptions.

Comment: No, still the same page.

Comment: Try to access your php file directly typing in browsers address bar its address. Also it could be because of incorrect regex syntax if you use one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look for `ErrorDocument 500` in your Apache `httpd.conf` file. In there you'll see if your setup has an override for the default 500 error code - e.g. `ErrorDocument 500 /http_codes/http_code_500.html`

Answer (score 0):

It's server's error page. It's generated by misconfiguration (like a typo in .htaccess), much earlier than ZF's `index.php` is requested. You can't fix this using ZF - you need to fix your server.